# Cannot connect to my database from within SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

[image]

The instance is running, but I still cannot connect, I get this error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to PC-CARLA\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Interfaces de red SQL, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Any suggestions on what can be going wrong? Why doesn't this thing connect? :S

How do I find the instance **NAME** of a server? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Has it ever connected OK?  If not, make sure you have the correct network protocols enabled. Have you tried restarting the service?  Also there may be something useful logged  in the Event Viewer for that computer.

Comment: @Sergio: Try the other things I mentioned.  You also said "No", but you are saying "no" to what? No it has never connected successfully, or no, you have not tried to restart the service?

Comment: Did you enable TCP IP connection ?

Comment: @gmagana: This is a fresh install on a machine that has never had SQL installed. I've also shut off the firewall. Both Management Studio and the Database itself are on the same machine.

Comment: @Sergio Try making connection to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.  It may be because the name PC-CARLA is not reachable or conflicted with another machine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the correct protocol(s) in your SQL Server Configuration Manager.

It is the second option in the screenshot you provided ("SQL Server Network Configuration").

You need to enable the protocols you need (all of them to make sure?) and then you need to restart the SQLEXPRESS service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak whatever language that error message is in, but I'm guessing that it's similar to one that I've seen in a language that I do know.  I think it's saying that the target machine may not be configured for remote connections.  Whenever I see that, there's either a firewall between the host and client, the specific instance is down, or there is a problem with the SQL browser.  As a test, can you telnet to the port that the SQL server is configured to run on?

Comment: Firewall is shut off, but even so the Server and Management studio are on the same machine.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, the SQL Browser service is stopped.  Try starting that up and see if that fixes it.  Also, if your host and client are on the same machine, try using "." as your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Thul is correct. You are getting this problem because the SQL Browser service is stopped.

By default (when using the full version of SQL Server but not SQL Express), SQL Server starts up and listens for connections on TCP port 1433. When you connect from SQL Management Studio (or your application) and don't specify a port, it tries to connect using 1433.

However - this is different for SQL Server Express (and other named instances of SQL Server). These start on a dynamic port and rely on the SQL Browser Service (UDP/1434) to provide the mapping between instance name and port.

So, in your example - you try and connect to ServerName\SQLEXPRESS. As it's not the default instance a connection is attempted to the SQL Browser service, which would then respond with the dynamic port of SQL Express (say port 12345). Finally, your SQL client will connect to ServerName port 12345 and will find your named instance.

In short - enable the browser service!