# What exactly are Service Accounts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Today I've tried to install a SQL Server to a machine with no success:

[Cannot connect to my database from within SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926880/cannot-connect-to-my-database-from-within-sql-management-studio)

So today I saw a tutorial for installing it step by step and the site didn't show anything different to what I did, **except** when choosing Service Accounts:

http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/installing-microsoft-sql-2008-express-edition

I chose: "Administrador" in the account area. And in the tutorial he chose, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

Would this cause the problems I was having in my previous question of not allowing me to enter the sql server from the Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are the Windows users that own each process that is needed to run SQL Server.

Since SQL Server is (usually) running even when no one is logged on to the server you have to enter the username that SQL Server should use.

Comment: So to answer the question, would this cause the error I experienced in my previous SO post?

Comment: Probably not, but I answered the question in the title of this question. Have you tried all sugestions in that question? The one I gave an upvote is the reason I usually get that error.